# Excel conditional formatting based on adjacent cell is highlighting wrong values

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel document that's got project due dates in column G, and actual completion dates in column H. I'm trying to use conditional formatting to change the font color on dates that are overdue in red. Some of the dates in Column G are based on references to other cells, ie, 90 days after Column F.

So far, I've used conditional formatting to set the cell range as

```
$H:$H
```

and then choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and use either

```
=$H2>$G2
```

or

```
=$H2>OFFSET($H2,-1,0)
```

I've also tried putting the equations in Column G in parenthess, i.e. for G2, the formula would be

```
=(F2+90)
```

instead of just

```
=F2+90
```

but this does not affect the results.

I expect this formula to change the font color to red for dates in column H that are greater than the dates in column G directly to the left, but what happens is that only some of the cells where H is greater than G get changed to red, and some cells where H is equal to or less than G get changed to red as well.

For example, I get:

```
Due (G)     | Completed (H)
------------------------
6/5/2017    | 6/5/2017*
9/3/2017    | 7/19/2018
2/10/2018   | 12/20/2017*
3/20/2018   | 6/15/2018*
9/13/2018   | 9/11/2018*
12/10/2018  | 12/19/2018*
3/19/2019   | 3/6/2019
```

With the asterisked dates in red. So the rule is sometimes incorrectly being applied to values in column H that are less than or precisely equal to column G, and sometimes incorrectly not being applied to values in column H that are actually greater than column G.

I've spent hours searching for the answer to this, but everything I find says that what I've just done should work perfectly, so what in the world am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any chance the data in G or H isn't in Date format? If Excel sees it as text format, then that can cause issues.

Comment: Please try using `=$H1>$G1` rather than `=$H2>$G2` if your range for conditional formatting is the whole column `$H:$H`.

Comment: @Lisa Thank you, that fixed it! It turned actual text I have at the top of my "Completed" column red, but that could be manually changed.